# won't read my file in C++ in the login

Tags: c++, codeblocks

it does write in my file but it seems like it won't read any. it keeps saying "incorrect username or password" , can anyone see the error??? this is the code that i have made, ios::app is for append right> is something like that needed in ifstream as well???  i really don;t know what else to say. i have been trying to get this work the whole day today.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int command; string name,password,inName, inPassword,regName,regPassword;
 while(1)
 {


    cout<< " 1. REGISTER \n 2. LOGIN \n 3. EXIT" <<"\n\n";
    cout<< "ENTER YOUR COMMAND NUMBER: \n";
    cin>>command;
    if (command==3)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (command == 1)
    {
        ofstream g("Registration.txt", fstream::app);
        if (!g.is_open())
        {
            cout<< "no such file exists \n";
            return 0;
        }
        cout<< "\n\n\n Enter new username: ";
        cin>> regName;
        cout<< "\n New Password: ";
        cin>> regPassword;
        g<<regName; g<<"\n";
        g<< regPassword;
        g.close();
    }

    if (command == 2)
    {
        ifstream f("Registration.txt");
        if (!f.is_open())
        {
            cout<< "could not open file \n";
            return 0;

        }
        getline(f,name,'\n');
        getline(f,password,'\n');
        f.close();

        while (1)
        {
            cout<< "\n\n\n"<< "Enter username: ";
            cin>>inName;
            cout<< "Enter password: ";
            cin>> inPassword;
            if (inName==name && inPassword== password)
            {
                cout << "\n\n\nLOGIN SUCCESSFUL! \n\n\n Welcome!"<< inName;
                break;
            }
            cout<< "INCORRECT USERNAME OR PASSWORD";
        }

        }
    }

  return 1;
 }
```

Comment: Do the contents of your  `registration.txt` file match your expectation? If so, have you tried attaching a debugger and inspecting the contents of `name` and `password` ?

Comment: If you don't have a debugger at least print the values of name name and password using `cout`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to write a `\n` after the password:

```
  g << regName; g << "\n";
  g << regPassword;
  g << "\n";   //<<<<<<
  g.close();
```

Better use this code:

```
  g << regName << "\n" << regPassword << "\n";
```

But you have another problem in the "login" part: you only compare the username and the password entered with the first usename/password pair in the file.

I let you fix this yourself as an exercise.